# How can I hide a local disk in Finder at root level?

Tags: macos, finder, hard-drive

I want to hide some local disks from left pane (`Devices` section) in Finder.

- I want to remove them from the list of all disks at root level.
- What is the command in terminal?

PS: I can't unmount them because they must be accessible for the system.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
/usr/bin/SetFile -a V /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
```

You will need to get the command line tools installed from Xcode if your system lacks the setfile program.

Comment: There is no SetFile command in `/usr/bin/` folder. It's not found by Finder on whole system disk.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd... I suggest you go with the answer of gentmatt... My apologies, I'll check into this later this evening if you insist by doing it using the Terminal

Comment: Setfile gets installed as part of the command line tools from Xcode. Installation steps depend on which version of Xcode you have installed.